# sqlite not opening db file on local drive

Tags: sqlite, perl, macos-monterey

I've recently upgraded to a new M1 running Monterey. My existing sqlite db files exist on an external drive and I can access them with Perl via DBI. But when I copy the .db files to my local internal drive, sqlite is not able to open them.

```
$dbh=DBI->connect('dbi:SQLite:dbname=/Users/trudge/MyDB/kb.db','','') or die    $DBI::errstr;
```

throws this error:
DBI connect('dbname=/Users/trudge/MyDB/kb.db','',...) failed: unable to open     database file at /Users/trudge/http/cgi-bin/kb/index.pl line 74.
unable to open database file at /Users/trudge/http/cgi-bin/kb/index.pl line 74.

I've recompiled sqlite3 (SQLite version 3.38.1 2022-03-12 13:37:29) but still no joy.

Not sure if this is a DBI problem, or an sqlite problem, or an Apple problem. Apparently the DBI supports sqlite 3.3 which should not be an issue.

Permission & ACL:

```
    -rwxrw-rw-  1 trudge  staff   102400 Mar 10 12:20 ephemera.db
    -rw-rw-rw-@ 1 trudge  staff   458752 Mar  5 17:19 kb.db
    -rwxrw-rw-  1 trudge  staff    90112 Mar 10 12:20 kba.db
    -rwxrw-rw-  1 trudge  staff   262144 Mar 10 12:20 library.db
    -rwxrw-rw-  1 trudge  staff  1630208 Mar  7 20:13 tunes3.db
```

I would appreciate any advice or suggestions as to why this is an issue and how I might solve it.

Comment: What's the @ sign in the permissions of the ls output for your kd.db mean? That might have something to do with the problem.

Comment: Ah, [extended attributes](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/42177). The answer in that link about a quarantine attribute sounds like it *might* be useful, but I'm not familiar with modern OS X.

Comment: Note that write permissions to the directory might also be needed. You could try running under `strace` or the like to find more info about what is presumably a failing sys call.

Comment: If the app is sandboxed, you cannot open random files in your file system.

Comment: Shawn yes extended attributes (access control) is a whole other level of security which I know little about. xattr is the command to mangle them.

Answer (score 0):

Such a simple solution. I checked permissions on my remote site (hosted) for the DB files. The directory was 755. My local system was not. Once I made the changes locally I finally had access to all the sqlite db files.

Apologies for such a newb oversight. Maybe I should retire from this.